# Get queryset of many-to-many field under another many-to-many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I am working on a User/Role/Permission model in django, where the model structure is this.

```
class GlobalPermission(BasicAbstractClass):
    TYPE_CHOICES = ["user_level", "platform_level", "user_platform_access_level"]

    short_code = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=92, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=189, blank=True, null=True)
    type = EnumField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'global_permission'

class Role(BasicAbstractClass):
    ROLE_CHOICES = ["admin", "analyst", "moderator", "editor", "superuser", "developer"]
    SERVICE_CHOICES = ["social_media_management", "survey"]

    service = EnumField(choices=SERVICE_CHOICES)
    name = EnumField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(GlobalPermission, related_name="role_permissions", blank=True, through="RolePermission")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " of " + self.service

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'role'
class RolePermission(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(GlobalPermission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "role_permissions"

class UserAccount(models.Model):
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, related_name="+", blank=True, through="UserRole")

class UserRole(BasicAbstractClass):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "user_role"
```

What I want here, is to get the list of permissions of a user. Here, the user may be assigned multiple roles, and I want a queryset containing all the permissions for those roles.

Comment: related_name="+"?

Comment: I don't need to know the users under a role. So I disabled it using "+" for related name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the thing you want (`GlobalPermission`) and then work backwards in the query:

```
GlobalPermission.objects.filter(role_permissions__user_accounts=target_user).distinct()
```

Note that you need a way to reference `UserAccount` in a query, such as:

```
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True, through="UserRole",
                                   related_name="+", related_query_name="user_accounts")
```